# Bootstrap5 responsive table overflowing flex box

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I am attempting to use a fixed-width `div` as a left side bar. The main content on the right of the side bar renders correctly unless there is a table with many columns. In this case, it overflows exactly the width of the side bar before the scroll bar is available. How can I fix this issue?

I've tried a couple layouts. The closest success was setting the table's `max-width` to `calc(100% - 248px)`: https://jsfiddle.net/t0qhoz1e/. This works if the table is overflowing. However, there might not always be columns or rows in my application long enough to cause overflow. In that case, there is a `248px` gap on the right: https://jsfiddle.net/euad3q71/. Removing the side bar also causes the table to render properly, but I would really like to have it. Any help or pointers appreciated, thanks.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid d-flex p-0 wrapper">
  <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 bg-light" style="width: 248px;">side bar</div>
  <div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="row">some table controls</div>
    <div class="table-responsive card flex-fill">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
            <th>Column3</th>
            <th>Column4</th>
            <th>Column5</th>
            <th>Column6</th>
            <th>Column7</th>
            <th>Column8</th>
            <th>Column9</th>
            <th>Column10</th>
            <th>Column11</th>
            <th>Column12</th>
            <th>Column13</th>
            <th>Column14</th>
            <th>Column15</th>
            <th>Column16</th>
            <th>Column17</th>
            <th>Column18</th>
            <th>Column19</th>
            <th>Column20</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>row</th>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>row</th>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>row</th>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>row</th>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>row</th>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>row</th>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>row</th>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>row</th>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>row</th>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>row</th>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>row</th>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>row</th>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>row</th>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>row</th>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>row</th>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>row</th>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>row</th>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>row</th>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>row</th>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>row</th>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th>row</th>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="row">some pagination controls</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI, you should probably be using Bootstrap mechanisms instead of your custom wrapper class. All that is available in the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The responsive table wrapper needs to know its limits. Do that by managing overflow on the element around it. I've added Bootstrap's `overflow-hidden` class.

I've also added columns to the rows above and below the table because their negative side margins were causing issues. You may not actually want to use rows there.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid d-flex p-0 wrapper">
  <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 bg-light" style="width: 248px;">side bar</div>

  <div class="d-flex flex-column overflow-hidden">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">some table controls</div>
    </div>

    <div class="card flex-fill table-responsive">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
            <th>Column3</th>
            <th>Column4</th>
            <th>Column5</th>
            <th>Column6</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>row</th>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">some pagination controls</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will get `vh-100 min-vh-100 w-100 overflow-hidden` added in place of the `wrapper` class as well. My table controls are columns much like your answer so it is not a problem 